# TypeError when using scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, odeint

I'm trying to solve a set of coupled differential equations using `scipy.integrate.odeint`. However when I try to run the program I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe' odepack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.`

Here is the code I use:

```
V = "v**2/2*log(1+x**2 + (y/a)**2 + (z/c)**2)" 
var = ['x','y','z']

def afleiden(func, var):
    f = sympify(func)
    partAfg = [f.diff(var[i]) for i in range(len(var))]
    return partAfg



init=[0.3,0.2,0.9,0.2,0.6,0.7] 

def func(rv, t, pot, var):
    return rv[3:6] + afleiden(pot,var) 

# rv is a list with 6 elements of witch the last 3 are part of the diff equations

t = np.arange(0,10,0.01)

y = odeint(func, init, t, args=(V, var,))
```

Could it be because the equations from `afleiden` are calculated using Sympy and thus probably `sypmpy` expressions? If so, is there anything i can do about it? I tried using lambdify but that didn't work out.

Comment: Modify `afleiden` to convert the sympy expressions to floating point values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Warren Weckesser says and as you suspected, you need to lambdify the expressions first, so that the various partial derivatives `dV/dvar[j]` return a floating point value.

More in general, one problem of your `afleiden` function is that it evaluates the analytical derivatives of `V`, without calculating the value of those expressions. I assume that `v,a,c` are parameters of your problems, deacribing a potential function `V(x,y,z)`. I also assume that your o.d.e. is

`dX/dt = dV/dX(x,y,z)`,

where `X=[x,y,z]` is your list of variables.

If this is the case, then you have 3 diff. equations, and not `6` as in your `func()` (a sum of lists is the concatenation of the lists, not the list of the sums).

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import lambdify, sympify
from scipy.integrate import odeint

var = ['x', 'y', 'z']
V = sympify("v**2/2*log(1+x**2 + (y/a)**2 + (z/c)**2)")
dVdvar_analytical = [V.diff(var[i]) for i in range(len(var))]
dVdvar = [lambdify(('x', 'y', 'z', 'v', 'a', 'c'), df) for df in dVdvar_analytical]

def afleiden(variables, _, params, dVdvar):
    x, y, z = variables
    v, a, c = params
    return [dVdvarj(x, y, z, v, a, c) for dVdvarj in dVdvar ]

variables0, params = [0.3, 0.2, 0.9], [0.2, 0.6, 0.7]

t = np.arange(0, 10, .1)
y = odeint(afleiden, variables0, t, args=(params, dVdvar))
plot(t, y)
```

Consistently with your expression for the potential `V`, the origin is a repellor and the point `y(t)` tends to infinity in the simulation for large times. if you add a minus sign at the begin of the expression, the origin becomes an attractor and the solution converges to `0`:

```
#example with minus sign
V = sympify("-v**2/2*log(1+x**2 + (y/a)**2 + (z/c)**2)")
t = np.arange(0, 100, .1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was very usefull! I was wondering if there is a way of using a list of the parameters and the variables in the lambdify expression instead of explicitly typing them. That way it would be easy to just change the potetial, the parameters and the variables at the top of the program and it would run anyway. 

I also don't get what the '_' does in afleiden.

Comment: If there is a way, it is not straightforward, as `lambdify` requires to specify `args`. Notice that if you keep the number of variables and the number of parameters fixed, you can still change the potential and run it anyway. The `_` is the time parameter `t` present in your original code. Since the system is autonomous, there's no use of the variable time, and I renamed it to `_`. This is a convention, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python)